# Add property to body when logged in

Tags: php, jquery

I want to add the `contenteditable` property to body once the user logged in, I am trying this:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    if( isset( $_SESSION['user'] ) ){//sino existe
         echo "<script>$('body').attr('contenteditable', 'true');</script>";    
    }
?>
```

and also tried this:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    if( isset( $_SESSION['user'] ) ){//sino existe
       echo "<script>$('body').prop('contenteditable', true);</script>";
    }
?>
```

What I'm doing wrong?

PD: this code is in the header of the index.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why use JS? You're already using PHP:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    if( isset( $_SESSION['user'] ) ): //sino existe ?> 
        <body contenteditable="true">
    <?php else: ?>
        <body>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Before writting this code you must ensure that you have loaded `jquery`, also write your code in `ready()` like,

```
<?php
    session_start();
    if( isset( $_SESSION['user'] )  and $_SESSION['user']){//exists and not empty
        echo "<script>
             $(function(){
                $('body').prop('contenteditable', true);
             });
          </script>";
    }
?>
```

Hope, this works.

Answer (score 1):

Your forgetting that this needs to run when the document is ready. To do so with JQuery try this (notice how it is now wrapped in the JQuery shorthand for 'on document ready').

```
<?php
    session_start();
    if( isset( $_SESSION['user'] ) ){//sino existe
            echo "<script> 
                      $(function(){ 
                          $('body').prop('contenteditable', true);    
                      });
                 </script>";

    }
?>
```